# "patch" command (version 2.0-12u11-Apple) does not include "--dry-run" Parameter in macOS Ventura

Tags: terminal, command-line, software-update

A collegue of mine upgraded to macOS Ventura, since then the parameter `--dry-run` is not available for the `patch` command anymore and our tools do not work automatically anymore as the command prompts for user input.

The version of `patch` is `2.0-12u11-Apple` on Ventura while being `2.5.8` on Monterey.

Is there a known way of how to solve this (for example an upgrade for the `patch` binary)?

See also

- https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43008/applying-patches-that-time-out-on-composer-update
- https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/423

Comment: Interesting. According to the man page, `-C, --check, --dry-run` is supported; according to `patch -h` it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`brew install gpatch` or `sudo port install gpatch` installs version `2.7.6` for which the `--dry-run` option is available again.